# How to redirect with id in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a controller store function like that :

```
    public function store_induk_pencairan(Request $request)
    {
    $new_id = $request->id;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $this->validate($request, [
        
        'rek_id' => 'required',
        'suplier_id' => 'required',
        'tgl_pengajuan' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required',
       
    ]);

    $induk = IndukPencairan::create([
       'rek_id' => $request['rek_id'],
       'user_id' =>  $id,
       'suplier_id' => $request['suplier_id'],
       'tgl_pengajuan' => $request['tgl_pengajuan'],
       'status' => $request['status'],
     
    ]);

    if ($induk) {
        return ['redirect' => route('get_detail'/.new_id)];// on here i need to redirect to this route but i have error 500 . 
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => ' Gagal update!',
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

if i remove this **/.new_id** and change to another route its work , can someone corect my code ?

or i need to use **redirect->to()**

*UPDATE its my route

```
Route::get('get_detail/{id}', 'PengadaanController@get_detail')->name('get_detail');
Route::post('store_induk_pencairan', 'PengadaanController@store_induk_pencairan')->name('store_induk_pencairan');
```

Comment: can you  share you what you write in your web.php for this route 
 = route('get_detail'/.new_id)) ?

Comment: Share your route please

Comment: i update my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **save**, `$induk->id` should be the last created id. 
And pass it with route like this :

```
 return redirect()->route('get_detail', $induk->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

also you can do it like

```
 return redirect()->route('profile', [$user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :
i think it should works

```
return redirect ()->route('get_detail/'. $new_id);
```

Comment: Route [get_detail/] not defined."

Comment: so use try this, route('get_detail' .'/'. $new_id);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
return redirect()->route('get_detail', ['id' =>$induk->id]);
```

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: get_detail] [URI: pengadaan/get_detail/{id}].

Comment: @AdhikMulat sorry my misunderstanding. Now I change